# Spotting LaTeX math common mistakes

Tags: windows-7, math, latex

I am looking for a program that can read a LaTeX file and give a warning (+ ideally a fix suggestion) for each common mistake it spots in math formulas. If possible, free and works with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Examples of common mistake in LaTeX math mode:

1) [Differentials](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/02/15/top-latex-mistakes/): $\int_0^1 f(x)  dx$ instead of $ \int_0^1 f(x) **\,** dx$ :

[image]

2) [Multi-letter function names](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/02/15/top-latex-mistakes/): $log e^x = x$ instead of $\log e^x = x$:

[image]

3) [Wrong kinds of dots](http://recursed.blogspot.com/2013/05/ten-common-latex-errors.html): "$x,...,y$" instead of $x, \ldots, y $.

It would be even greater if it could give warnings for all the LaTeX writing, not just the math mode, e.g. one common mistake is writing "Yes." instead of ``Yes.'':

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few but the one I would recommend is [ChkTeX](http://baruch.ev-en.org/proj/chktex/).

From the web page:

- Supports over 40 warnings. Warnings include:

  - Commands terminated with space. Ignores ``\tt\'', etc.
  - Space in front of references instead of ``~''.
  - Forgetting to group parenthesis characters when
        sub-/superscripting.
  - Italic correction (``/'') mistakes (double, missing,
        unnecessary).
  - Parenthesis and environment matching.
  - Ellipsis detection; also checks whether to use ``\dots'',
        ``\cdots'' or ``\ldots''.
  - Enforcement of normal space after abbreviation. Detects most
        abbreviations automagically.
  - Enforcement of end-of-sentence space when the last sentence
        ended with capital letter.
  - Math-mode on/off detection.
  - Quote checking, both wrong types (``"'') and wrong direction.
  - Recommends splitting three quotes in a row.
  - Searching for user patterns.
  - Displays comments.
  - Space in front of ``\label'' and similar commands.
  - Use of ``x'' instead of ``$\times$'' between numbers.
  - Multiple spaces in input which will be rendered as one space
        (or multiple spaces, where that is undesirable).
  - Warns about text which may be ignored.
  - Mathematical operators typeset as variables.
  - No space in front of/after parenthesis.
  - Demands a consistent quote style.
  - Punctuation inside inner math mode/outside display math mode.
  - Use of TeX primitives where LaTeX equivalents are available.
  - Space in front of footnotes.

Comment: "There are quite a few" - Could you name others?

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/lacheck/, http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/check/, http://www.cs.umd.edu/~nspring/software/style-check-readme.html, http://textlint.lukas-renggli.ch/, http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nag